# find numbers in string in selenium

Tags: python, selenium

In Python and Selenium, how do I find numeric characters in a text and put them in a variable?
for example :

text = Your verification code is: 5674

I need to find the number 5674 from the text and put it in a variable.

Result »» x = 5674

---

import re
txt = "Your verification code is: 5674"
x = is_digit(txt)
print(x)

x »»» 5674

Answer (score 0):

If the message is always formatted like this you can do:

```
text[text.find(":"):].strip() # -> 5764
```

or

```
text.strip("Your verification code is:") # -> 5764
```

Answer (score 0):

Well if you really expect just a *single* verification integer at the end, you could use `re.search()`:

```py
text = "Your verification code is: 5674";
code = re.search(r'\d+$', text).group()
print(code)  # 5674
```